# tiny selection elements in firefox

Tags: firefox, 17.10, appearance, scrollbar

I am using Firefox 57.0.1 in Ubuntu 17.10 (with Radiance Appearance) and it shows tiny selection elements and scrollbars.

[image: screenshot with selection box and scrollbar]

I have tried to set `GtkRange::slider-width` in `/usr/share/themes/Radiance`, but this did not help.